# Android Java - Using Handlers Inside For Loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I have a for loop which calls a function to download a file.
Each time the function is called the title of the file is displayed in a TextView.
The problem is the files are downloaded but the UI freezes up, and it is only after the files have finished downloading that the UI is updated, and only the last title for the last file is shown.

```
for(int i=0; i < Titles.size(); i++){

    downloading.setText("Downloading: "+Titles.get(i));
    if(!Utils.downloadFile(Mp3s.get(i))){
        downloading.setText("ERROR Downloading: "+Titles.get(i));

    }

}
```

I know I have to use a Handler or Thread to sort this issue out.
But I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) - something like:

```
// Move download logic to separate thread, to avoid freezing UI.
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i < Titles.size(); i++) {
      // Those need to be final in order to be used inside 
      // Runnables below.
      final String title = Titles.get(i);

      // When in need to update UI, wrap it in Runnable and
      // pass to runOnUiThread().
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          downloading.setText("Downloading: "+title);
        }
      });

      if(!Utils.downloadFile(Mp3s.get(i))) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            downloading.setText("ERROR Downloading: "+title);
          }
        });
    }
  }
}).start();
```

That's pretty verbose (yeah, Java!) and, in my opinion, not very readable.

Another solution would be to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which has convienient `onProgressUpdate()` method designed to update UI for a long-running task. It could look like:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, String, Void> {
  // This method will be run off the UI thread, no need to 
  // create separate thread explicitely.
  protected Long doInBackground(URL... titles) {
    for(int i=0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      publishProgress("Downloading " + titles[i]);
      if(!Utils.downloadFile(Mp3s.get(i))) {
        publishProgress("ERROR Downloading: " + titles[i]);
      }
    }
  }

   // This method will be called on the UI thread, so
   // there's no need to call `runOnUiThread()` or use handlers.
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     downloading.setText(progress[0]);
   }
}
```

(please note that code above is hand-written not-compiled, so it's probably buggy, but it should give you an idea how to go from here.